# Is there any way to see base-v1 policy, what built in User Flows are referring to?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

**Context**

I have a working POC web application what is using Azure B2C built in User Flows.
Now I downloaded one of my built in User Flow just to read and understand what is under hood.
However it refers to `base-v1`

```
<BasePolicy>
  <TenantId>myb2c.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
  <PolicyId>base-v1</PolicyId>
</BasePolicy>
```

**Question**

Where or how can I see the content of this `base-v1` policy?

Comment: Have got a confirmation from Microsoft support that `base-v1` is internal policy and is not exposed. As Alfredo Revilla suggests, You can download the custom policy starter pack is for learning purposes. They should be similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such policies are not intended to be downloaded, but they're pretty much [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview) tailored to support user flows.

I recommed you to review the [Custom policy starter pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started?tabs=applications#custom-policy-starter-pack).

Comment: .....I know..... I meant to _see_ like a source code for example for learning purposes.

Comment: The custom policy starter pack is there for learning purposes.

Comment: We have several user flows with many custom claims. For new requirements I need to customize the policy directly in xml. Is there any way to gather the current policies? I don't like to start from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to get the XML source of your custom user flow **along with the base policy** settings.
It's described in this [Blog post](https://blog.wojtek.pro/azure-ad-b2c-custom-policies-how-to-begin/).

Now it's much easier to get all the settings especially localization resources.

Comment: Is there no way to get the TrustFramweworkExtensions?